# In E6, what happens about Hit Points after level 6? Do characters stop gaining HP?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, hit-points, e6

Apologies if this is the incorrect way to ask a question or if it was already answered.
In E6, what happens about Hit Points after level 6?  Do characters stop gaining HP?

I'm keen to try E6, and see most of the issues that could crop up have been answered, but:
How do characters gain more HP after level 6?  Or don't they?

Answer (score 13):

### No more HP from levels, but there are other ways to gain HP if you invest in them

Since an E6 character stops gaining levels once they reach 6th level, they will get no more hit points from levelling up and getting new hit dice. That's simply not a thing that can happen to them any more. However, that does not mean they are stuck with their current hit point maximum for the rest of time, since they now progress by gaining new *feats*, and there are feats available in the system which will grant additional hit points.

In 3.5e, the feat [Toughness](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#toughness) from the core rules will grant an additional 3hp and is one of those feats that can be taken repeatedly; this is normally a terrible feat choice in standard D&D as it's a very inefficient use of the limited number of feats you get. In an E6 game where you can hypothetically gain new feats forever you might conceivably reach a point where a couple more HP are more use to you than any other feat you can find, and you can take it as many times as you like. If you have access to it, the Improved Toughness feat in *Complete Warrior* grants an extra hit point per hit die, which makes it twice as useful as Toughness for an E6 character (it doesn't even have Toughness as a prerequisite, but it can only be taken once).

In Pathfinder, the core [Toughness](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/toughness/) was reworked so that it already improves with extra HD, but can no longer be taken multiple times. So unless there are more feats out there which improve hit points directly - I couldn't find any with a quick search but I don't rule out their existence - that puts a bit more of a limit on your possible hit point advancement.

As well as those options, any effect which improves your Constitution will also improve your HP. The E6 rules you're using might include feats which allow you to slightly improve ability scores (such as the Ability Training and Ability Advancement feats in [this E6 ruleset](https://esix.pbworks.com/f/E6v041.pdf) or [this pathfinder version](http://p6codex.com/AbridgedP6CodexV0p2.pdf)). Besides inherent improvement, you may also find or purchase new magical items that provide better enhancements to constitution and thus further improve hit points.

Comment: Oddly—but honestly it’s good design—Improved Toughness does not, in fact, require Toughness. It requires a base Fort save bonus of +2.

Comment: @KRyan you're quite right - I think I accidentally conflated it with a different feat I saw while looking them up.

Comment: Thanx.  Appreciate the response.  I think I might also allow a player to add a hit dice at the 5 000 XP mark, instead of an extra feat/ability. Can't see many players choosing this, but I think I may allow it.

Comment: @NickCTZA assume a barbarian actually *does* take that a couple of times and your combats are getting seriously unbalanced: that barbarian basically becomes unkillable!

Comment: @Trish - great point.  Thanx. Much appreciated.

Comment: Extra hit die is also great for casters. Combined with the practiced spellcaster feat, that’s a significant boost and lets you bootstrap into the crazy part of magic.

Comment: Are the Masters of the Wild toughness feats usually available in E6?